# MultiPeer MCNearbyBrowserService Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, p2p, multipeer-connectivity

I have an application that is using the MultiPeer Connectivity framework. Every time the application becomes active in AppDelegate, I make a new MCSession a MCNearbyBrowserService, and a MCNearbyAdvertiserService and call start browsing and start advertising. Then every time the application becomes inactive in AppDelegate, I stop browsing and advertising and set everything to nil. I find that MCNearbyBrowserService causes a crash in its syncQueue:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -    [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2de3ee8b 0x381396c7 0x2dd7caef 0x2dd7c8b3 0x2f648167 0x2f6493af 0x3861e103 0x38622e77 0x3861ff9b 0x38623751 0x386239d1 0x3874ddff 0x3874dcc4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

sometimes when the app reopens.

Here is my code for applicationDidBecomeActive:

```
self.myIdentifier = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[self.class createHash:20]];

self.mainSession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.myIdentifier];
self.mainSession.delegate = self;

peerAdvertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:self.myIdentifier discoveryInfo:nil serviceType: service];
peerAdvertiser.delegate = self;
peerBrowser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:self.myIdentifier serviceType: service];
peerBrowser.delegate = self;

acceptReset = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(reset) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
acceptPosts = true;
[peerBrowser startBrowsingForPeers];
[peerAdvertiser startAdvertisingPeer];

self.isBrowsing = true;
```

and here is my code for applicationWillResignActive:

```
[acceptReset invalidate];
[peerAdvertiser stopAdvertisingPeer];
[peerBrowser stopBrowsingForPeers];
[self.mainSession disconnect];
self.mainSession = false;
self.isBrowsing = false;
```

The full code can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/E3wY6U4N

Comment: Any luck with this? I am having a similar problem... but having a hard tim finding a solution...!

Comment: At the end I had to drop multitasking. It's sad that Apple's library is so buggy.

Comment: I'm receiving the exact same exception.  In my case this is following a PeerNotConnected notification before I've even started the invitations/accept.

Comment: I'm seeing this when an advertiser is disconnecting and the browser tries to invite (reconnect) to the advertiser.  It can take a little bit for the advertiser to actually go away and if the browser tries to connect to an advertiser that is going away this error will happen.  It's been very reproducible for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember running into this issue, and the quick fix was to nil out the delegates and release the browser and advertiser. So assuming your App Delegate has a strong property for each the setup method would look like:

```
self.peerAdvertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:self.myIdentifier discoveryInfo:nil serviceType: service];
self.peerAdvertiser.delegate = self;

self.peerBrowser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:self.myIdentifier serviceType: service];
self.peerBrowser.delegate = self;
```

And then when the app enters the background (or otherwise wants to stop browsing/advertising):

```
self.peerAdvertiser.delegate = nil;
[self.peerAdvertiser stopAdvertisingPeer];
self.peerAdvertiser = nil;

self.peerBrowser.delegate = nil;
[self.peerBrowser stopBrowsingForPeers];
self.peerBrowser = nil;

[self.mainSession disconnect];
```

I'd also recommend against creating a new `MCPeerID` on each app launch, as Multipeer Connectivity has a habit of discovering old peers, and you'll end up discovering your 'former self' on each relaunch.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I implemented this suggestion, and it worked fine, but now (9.3.1), `self.peerAdvertisier.stopAdvertisingPeer()` causes the app to randomly crash. Any ideas? Also, does the order of setting the delegate to nil, and stop advertising matter?

Comment: @coopersita I'd say setting the delegate to nil should happen before calling `stopAdvertisingPeer()` but not sure about the crash. You have any logs? Maybe start a new question for that one.

Comment: Thanks. I'll change the order, maybe that alone will fix it. I'm using crashlytics, so I don't have too much info on how this is happening, but if it does, I'll open a new question with what I have.